# Shell Script - How to get stuff between two separators

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, awk

I've got something like that:

```
xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse             id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CHICONY HP Basic USB Keyboard             id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And I want to get the id number.
I've try something like awk -F 'id=' '[print $2} but text after the id number is still here! How i can only get the id number!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the shortest, but should be easy to understand for anyone with a little bit of `awk` knowledge:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i ~ /id=/) { print substr($i, 4); break; } }'
```

Comment: may I suggest: `{print substr($i,4); break}` in place of your print statement

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
xinput --list | grep -Eo 'id=[0-9]+' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'
```

or

```
xinput --list | grep -Eo 'id=[0-9]+' | awk -F= '{print $2}'
```

Comment: nice solution.  requires GNU grep for -o

Answer (score 1):

one way

```
xinput --list | awk -F"id=" 'NF{split($2,a," ");print a[1]}' file
```

with the shell(bash)

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput --list | while read -r line
do
  case "$line" in
   *id=* )
     line=${line##*id=}
     echo ${line%% *}
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
xinput --list | while read line; do
    ID=`echo ${line} | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d\[ -f1 | xargs`
    echo ${ID}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash only:

```
while read line ; do
    if [[ $line =~ id=([[:digit:]]) ]] ; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
done < <( xinput --list )
```

Answer (score 0):

I find these things simplest with sed, using substitution of a group to capture the data you want and ensuring the rest of the line is matched in the regex.

```
sed 's/.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: that will include lines that don't have an id=, use -n to suppress initial output, and add a p at the end of the replacement to display only the replacement string... or does xinput --list only display lines with an id output?

Comment: I was basing it on the sample text provided by the poster, but you are correct regarding -n /p - another sed pattern I frequently use.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cat x | awk -Fid= '{print $2}' | awk  '{print $1}'
```